# How to add exceptions in matching subnet in iptables nat output chain?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, nat

I have a rule in my iptables config:

```
-t nat -A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
```

This rule prevents from routing packets sent to `10.X.X.X` address.
But now I want to add exception in this rule and allow subnet `10.192.0.0/16`.
How can I do that?
I've tried these rules:

```
-t nat -A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/8 ! -d 10.192.0.0/16 -j RETURN

-t nat -A OUTPUT -d 10.192.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
-t nat -A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
```

But they didn't work.
Also this rule

```
-t nat -A OUTPUT -d 10.192.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
```

is bad because I have other rules after these and accepting packet can prevent packet from matching further rules.

Hope for your help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if its just an error in what you typed here, but you used 10.192.0.0/8 instead of 10.192.0.0/16

Comment: You should provide *all* of your rules so people understand what's going on. Your explanations are incomplete right now. Please add result of `iptables-save -c`, as well as `ip -br address; ip route`.